# GameObject in SerializedField - OverRide - Apply All: Prefab Doesn't Update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I added a script to my prefab. Then I put my prefab into my scene and drag/dropped the GameObjects into the appropriate fields within the inspector. I then clicked OverRides>>Apply All. (Which is common and I do this all of the time)
However, the game object I'm using for the Spawn Zone when the Game Object will be Instantiated will not apply to my Prefab. (The Prefab in the scene does have the Empty Game Object attached but not the main Prefab in the Project panel)
I'm using the same method that I use for Instantiating bullets but for some unknown reason the Project view prefab will say "None(GameObject)"

Here's the code:

```
[SerializeField]
private GameObject boss;
[SerializeField]
private float bossSpd;
[SerializeField]
private GameObject bossSpawnZone1; // This won't apply to my prefab in Project panel

private void Update()
{
    if(startBoss == true)//StartBoss occurs when a GameObject is touched by player on another script. Just OnTriggerEnter2D set var to true
    {
        GetTheBoss();
    }
}
void GetTheBoss()
{
    Instantiate(boss, bossSpawnZone1.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    startBoss = false;
}
```

I would include pics but I don't know how to upload them in here. Never used the IMG  URL before. But trust me, I inserted the empty gameobject(SpawnZone) into the field. I also used the override to apply all. Yet the spawn zone field remains empty.

What I've tried:

1) Removing the script and re-adding it then filling the fields again.
2) Made the spawn zone public static and tried using GameObject.Find("PirateSpawnZone") in another script pertaining to the player.
3) Changing the variable name and saving the script.
4) Restarting Unity / Restarted computer completely then open Unity back up.

Comment: @derHugo I put the prefab into the scene and I inserted the fields on that prefab. Then I applied the update. All fields are filled except the spawnzone. I use this technique all the time so I'm confused as to why all of a sudden it is refusing to accept the gameobject upon Override>>Apply All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have Scene references in a prefab. It is not possible. It only works for GameObject reference that are themselves a prefab living in the asset or references within one and the same prefab hierarchy.

However some workarounds exist

### dependency injection

using dependency injection (e.g. [Zenject](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/zenject-dependency-injection-ioc-17758))

### ScriptableObject references

1. a [ScriptableObject](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects) for setting the reference on scene start and referencing the `ScriptableObject` instead.

   ```
   [CreateAssetMenu(filename = "new GameObjectReference", menuName = "ScriptableObject/GameObjectReference")]
   public GameObjectReference : ScriptableObject
   {
       public GameObject value;
   }
   ```
2. Create an Asset by <kbd>right click</kbd> in the Assets → `Create` → `ScriptableObject` → `GameObjectReference`
3. Then change your script field to

   ```
   [SerializeField] private GameObjectReference bossSpawnZone1;
   ```

   and everywhere where you use it use `bossSpawnZone1.value` instead.

   This works now since the ScriptableObject instance itself lives in the Assets.
4. Then finally you need the setter component on the `bossSpawnZone1` GameObject like

   ```
   public GameObjectReferenceSetter : MonoBehaviour
   {
       [SerializeField] private GameObject scriptableAsset;

       private void Awake()
       {
           scriptableAsset.value = gameObject;
       }
   }
   ```

### Singleton pattern

having only the setter and making a `public static` reference (only works if there is only exactly one of those reference in the entire scene/game

```
public class SpawnZoneReference : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameObject instance;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        instance = gameObject;
    }
}
```

And in your script instead use

```
Instantiate(boss, SpawnZoneReference.instance.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

Or very similar using only a certain type like

```
public class BossSpawnZone : MonoBehaviour { }
```

On the `GameObject` and in your script do

```
bossSpawnZone1 = FindObjectOfType<BossSpawnZone>();
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because you are 100% correct and not only that but very thorough with the explanation. However, my problem is that I forgot one key element... I was trying to instantiate the object on the movement script. So you were right in your first comment, it just took me awhile to figure it out. I fixed this by creating a "PirateSpawn" Script and put it on the object I wanted to trigger instantiation. Which allowed me to place the game objects into the fields. The bad part about all of this is that I know better than this, so I'm kinda embarrassed that I missed it!